# WPF Disable dragging update or update the value less frequently

Tags: c#, wpf, slider, controls

I made a videoplayer with mediaelement and I want either of these 2 things.

1. When I drag the slider to update the value less frequently so it won't be laggy
2. To disable updating the value when dragged and update on completed.

I tried this but then dragging is disabled. Any idea ?

```
public class SliderIgnoreDelta : Slider
{
    protected override void OnThumbDragDelta(DragDeltaEventArgs e)
    {
       // base.OnThumbDragDelta(e);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it ! See answers to update less freq [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/d796c93e-c58c-4632-b0ec-f2aa4f154cfe/wpf-disable-dragging-update-or-update-the-value-less-frequently?forum=wpf)

Answer (score 0):

If you are binding the slider's value to something you can use the Delay property of Binding. Slider is actually the example Microsoft gives for the typical use case of the Delay property.

```
<Slider Value="{Binding Path=Something, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay, Delay=500}"/>
```

Comment: i can't bind slider's value to mediaelement position , it's hard and i don't know